# Undefined index in $_POST with multiple select

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that contains a multiple `<select>` element. I want to be able to have PHP retrieve a list of all the options in the `<select>`.

The user can add items to the `<select>` by clicking various things on the page. This adds items to the `<select>` dynamically via JavaScript.

Skeleton of my HTML form:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <select id='list' name='items[]' multiple='multiple'>
    </select>

    <input type='submit' value='Save' />
</form>
```

And my `submit.php`:

```
<?php
    $list = $_POST["items"]; // returns 'undefined index' error
    for($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
        echo $list[$i] . "<br />";
    }
?>
```

I have been looking around a lot on this issue and can't find anything that works. I have tried changing everything with POST to GET and that doesn't change anything.

When I do `var_dump($_POST)`, I get:

```
array(0) { }
```

I am using an XAMPP server on my local machine, not sure if that is contributing to the issue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: may be new option added to the item through javascript are not bind on document .. could you please post your code to add items through javascript

Answer (score 0):

When there are no `<option>` elements in a `<select>`, or if none are selected, the form field will not be sent to the server.

You should always make sure POST (and GET) variables are set before using them:

```
if ( ! isset($_POST['items'])) {
    die('Not set: "items"');
}
```

For example:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <select id='list' name='items[]' multiple='multiple'>
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Save' />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['items']) and is_array($_POST['items'])) {
    $list = $_POST["items"];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
        echo $list[$i] . "<br />";
    }
} else {
    die('Not set: "items"');
}
```

Comment: There are options though. Does it make a difference if JavaScript adds them dynamically? Or does it only get sent if it lies in the static HTML?

Comment: If you still get the error then it is because nothing is selected.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

HTML:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <select id='list' name='items[]' multiple='multiple'>
        <option value="Test1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="Test2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="Test3">Test 3</option>
    </select>

    <input type='submit' value='Save' />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $list = $_POST["items"];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
        echo $list[$i] . "<br />";
    }
?>
```